# Spring MVC Controller not returning correct view

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a userName(jeff) stored in a cookie when the user request the officer/user page if there is a userName in the **cookie** i want show the user the officer/user details. I use an **ajax request** to get the details.

The **ajax** request goes to the **Controller** and gets the data however when i return the **view** to the user the **Object** is *null*. Therefore no data is bind to the object. The view is then empty. I would like to return to the user the object which has the officer/user data.

Under is my code and a screen shot of the request in firebug. Please tell me where i am going wrong.

**Ajax request from view**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function getCookie(name) {
    var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + name + "|;\s*"+ name + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g");
    var result = regexp.exec(document.cookie);
    return (result === null) ? null : result[1];
  }

  var userName = getCookie("userName");
  console.log(getCookie("userName"));

  if(userName != null & userName != 'Guest'){
     alert('Redirecting to get officer');

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
        url:'getOfficer/'+ userName + '.htm',
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        cache: false, 
        data:userName                   
        });     
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="getOfficer/{userName}.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView getOfficer(@PathVariable String userName,@ModelAttribute Officers officer, 
BindingResult result,ModelMap m,Model model,HttpServletRequest request,  
HttpServletResponse response) {

 logger.info("In get Officer by userName");
 try{
    model.addAttribute("officers",officerManager.getOfficer(userName));
 }catch(Exception e){
    logger.error("Exception In Officer Controller getOfficer/{userName} " + e.getMessage());
    request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
 }

 logger.info("about to return new officer_registration");
 logger.info("Officer Badge Number is "+officer.getBadgeNo());
 logger.info("Officer First and last name is "+officer.getfName() + " - " + officer.getlName());

 return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");    

}
```

**Error Log with Logger.info messages**

I noticed this line which states the model is null. Why?

```
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod  - Method [postOfficer] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'officer_registration'; model is null


758470 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] INFO  com.crimetrack.web.OfficerController  - In get Officer by userName
758470 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] INFO  com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - Getting Officer in getOfficer(String userName)
758506 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
758506 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = ?]
758506 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
758508 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [jeff], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
758510 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] INFO  com.crimetrack.web.OfficerController  - about to return new officer_registration
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] INFO  com.crimetrack.web.OfficerController  - Officer Badge Number is null
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] INFO  com.crimetrack.web.OfficerController  - Officer First and last name is null - null
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod  - Method [postOfficer] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'officer_registration'; model is null]
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod  - Invoking [initBinder] method with arguments [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder@b836456]
758512 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod  - Method [initBinder] returned [null]
758512 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'officer_registration'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/officer_registration.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'crimetrack'
758512 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView  - Rendering view with name 'officer_registration' with model {officers=com.crimetrack.business.Officers@5f305001, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.officers=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors} and static attributes {}
758512 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView  - Added model object 'officers' of type [com.crimetrack.business.Officers] to request in view with name 'officer_registration'
758512 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView  - Added model object 'userName' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'officer_registration'
758512 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView  - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.officers' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'officer_registration'
758513 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - No bean named 'requestDataValueProcessor' found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@726b5b3c: defining beans [citizenManager,validateCitizenManager,citizenDao,citizenTypeManager,citizenTypeDao,markerManager,markerDao,crimeHotSpotManager,crimeHotSpotDao,crimeManager,crimeRegistrationValidation,crimeDao,colorManager,colorDao,monitoringTypeManager,monitoringTypeDao,monitoringManager,monitoringDao,ethnicityManager,ethnicityDao,crimeLevelManager,crimeLevelDao,crimeTypeManager,crimeTypeDao,statusManager,statusDao,crimeCategoryManager,crimeCategoryDao,maritalStatusManager,maritalStatusDao,occupationManager,occupationDao,officerManager,countryManager,countryDao,authenticationManager,loginDao,divisionManager,divisionDao,positionManager,positionDao,genderManager,genderDao,officerRegistrationValidation,validateUserManager,officerDao,dataSource,propertyConfigurer,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
758513 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView  - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/officer_registration.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'officer_registration'
758514 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - No bean named 'requestDataValueProcessor' found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@726b5b3c: defining beans [citizenManager,validateCitizenManager,citizenDao,citizenTypeManager,citizenTypeDao,markerManager,markerDao,crimeHotSpotManager,crimeHotSpotDao,crimeManager,crimeRegistrationValidation,crimeDao,colorManager,colorDao,monitoringTypeManager,monitoringTypeDao,monitoringManager,monitoringDao,ethnicityManager,ethnicityDao,crimeLevelManager,crimeLevelDao,crimeTypeManager,crimeTypeDao,statusManager,statusDao,crimeCategoryManager,crimeCategoryDao,maritalStatusManager,maritalStatusDao,occupationManager,occupationDao,officerManager,countryManager,countryDao,authenticationManager,loginDao,divisionManager,divisionDao,positionManager,positionDao,genderManager,genderDao,officerRegistrationValidation,validateUserManager,officerDao,dataSource,propertyConfigurer,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
758528 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@51dd475f
758528 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
```

**Screen Shot**

The userName is **Jeff**

This is from firebug and it shows the POST jeff.htm is returning data. I think the view being returned is incorrect.

[image]

**Officer_Registration.jsp**

```
</head>
<body>
  <form:form id="officerRegistration" name="officerRegistration" method="post" modelAttribute="officers" action="officer_registration.htm">
  <ol>
  <li>
    <label>Badge No</label>
    <form:input path="badgeNo" id="badgeNo" title="Enter a Valid Badge Number"
      readonly="${badgeNoStatus}" class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="badgeNo" class="errors" />
    <label id="badgeNoErr"></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form:label for="userName" path="userName">User Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="userName" id="userName" title="Choose A Unique UserName"
      readonly="${userNameStatus}" class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="userName" class="errors" />
    <label id="userNameErr"></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Password</label>
    <form:password path="password" id="password" class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="password" class="errors" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Re-Enter Password</label>
    <form:password path="password2" id="password2"
      class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="password2" class="errors" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>e-Mail Address</label>
    <form:input path="emailAdd" id="emailAdd" title="Enter eMail Address"
      class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="emailAdd" class="errors" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <form:input path="fName" id="fName" title="Your First Name"
      class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="fName" class="errors" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <form:input path="lName" id="lName" title="Your Last Name"
      class="formData" />
    <form:errors path="lName" class="errors" />
  </li>
  <li>
```

Comment: What do you do with the data that the ajax request returns? It seems that your view is generated properly just looking at the image of the response in firebug. I suspect the problem is with the javascript that is supposed to update the form your looking at.

Comment: i do not have a success function for the returned object. Should i include a success function when the object returns ? how will it bind ?

Comment: I am trying to bind the object from the controller and returning the view so the object will display in the view

Comment: That's because you return a **new** `ModelAndView`, use another constructor to add your data

Comment: @RC. i dont understand what you mean by use another constructor to add data

Comment: @RC. you mean do a redirect to the page?

Comment: something like `new ModelAndView("officer_registration", "officers", officerManager.getOfficer(userName))`

Comment: do you have any jsp page like officer_registration? check spell

Comment: Just noticed that you included the code that makes the ajax request. I think you just need to add a `success` function see my answer.

Comment: @RC That is not necessary. The underlying `ModelAndViewContainer` will aggregate the attributes in the returned `ModelAndView` and those in the `ModelMap` and `Model` arguments passed to the method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you have a look at this question for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666549/spring-mvc-populating-object-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the last image in your question I can see that you are using jQuery and it looks like you are getting a response back containing HTML. I'm assuming that you are using jQuery to make the ajax-request (e.g. using `$.ajax` or `$.get`). Let's say you're using [jQuery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Your js-code would look something like:

```
function getOfficerInfo(officerUserName) {
    var officerUrl = "/crimeTrack/getOffice/" + officerUserName + ".htm"
    $.ajax({
        url: officerUrl,
        type: "GET"
    });
}
```

This would send a GET request to the server which would return the html that is showing in the response your viewing in the image. However, this code does not handle the response. In order to do that you would need to add a success field in the javascript object your are passing to the `$.ajax` function (OR you could use the fact that the  `$.ajax` function returns a promise, but let's stick to the basics :) ).

```
function getOfficerInfo(officerUserName) {
    var officerUrl = "/crimeTrack/getOffice/" + officerUserName + ".htm"
    $.ajax({
        url: officerUrl,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#form-container").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When the ajax request is successfull the `success` function will be called and the `data` variable will hold the data in the response. Here I'm assuming you have some an element on the page with the id `form-container` which content can be replaced with your html response.

Note that there is no error handling here so you should add a `error` function also to handle timeouts, serverside errors etc.

Finally. I would recommend that you transfer the data as JSON and just update the values in the existing form. Spring has excellent support for returning JSON using the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
public ModelAndView getOfficer(...){...}
```

Do this:

```
public String getOfficer(...) {
    ...
    return "officer_registration";
}
```

Spring will interpret that returned String as a view name and use the model you built within the method.

Comment: This is equivalent in behavior to what OP is currently doing.

Comment: Incorrect. The OP is returning a `ModelAndView` which includes a new EMPTY model along with the name of the view. Nothing he puts in the model will make it to the view.

Comment: Incorrect. Go see the source code of `ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler`, `MapMethodProcessor` and `ModelMethodProcessor`. The `Model` and `ModelMap` arguments passed to the handler method and the attributes contained inside them will be synchronized with those in the `ModelAndView` returned. In the end, all of those attributes will be included in the `ModelAndViewContainer` used for the request.

Comment: Ahhh you're right. (Apparently turned out not to be his problem anyway.) My bad.

Comment: Yeah, OP just wasn't aware of response handling with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Seems that this approach wouldn't help. Look Next tip**

You return new clear ModelAndView.

Try this instead:

```
ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("officer_registration");
m.addAllObjects(model.asMap());
return m;
```

**EDIT: This can help**

But if you want to request officer data only its better to create another method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getOfficer/{userName}.ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Officers getOfficerInfo(@PathVariable String userName) {
    return officerManager.getOfficer(userName);
}
```

Dont forget to add jackson dependency (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs).

In first case you will get plain text which will be html of your "officer_registration" page (it will look like "......). So it is unconvinient to parse officer data from such text

In the second case you will obtain officers object in json format. So it will be very easy to extract data from it.

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue? Looking at the last image in the question it seems like the response is generated with data. Could spring be merging the `Model` passed as an argument with the `ModelAndView` returned from the method automatically? I think that your code is much generally clearer in any case.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Adding model to ModelAndView wouldn't change the result.

Comment: I did not was to have to extract the data since i am using spring form tags and this should allow the fields to find the relevant attributes from the object.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
758511 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod  - Method [postOfficer] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'officer_registration'; model is null
```

prints that the `model` field in the returned `ModelAndView` is `null`.  This log statement comes from `InvocableHandlerMethod#invokeForRequest` and looks like this

```
if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
    logger.trace("Method [" + this.getMethod().getName() + "] returned [" + returnValue + "]");
}
```

Your `@Controller` handler method creates and returns a new `ModelAndView` object

```
return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");
```

The `ModelAndView` constructor that accepts a `String` does not initialize its `model` field. Therefore it remains `null`. **Don't be alarmed however.** The parameters `ModelMap` and `Model` that your handler method declares will both be passed the same argument of type `BindingAwareModelMap` which is resolved by a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. The specific implementation classes are `ModelMethodProcessor` for the `Model` parameter, and `MapMethodProcessor` for the `ModelMap`. Both of these resolve their target argument from the `ModelAndViewContainer` that is generated for each request. They will both give the same instance. It's redundant that you declare both.

Even though your `model` field in the returned `ModelAndView` is `null`, further down the request processing, it will be synchronized with the `BindingAwareModelMap` that was passed as an argument and will therefore contain the attribute you set with

```
model.addAttribute("officers",officerManager.getOfficer(userName));
```

or the error attribute, depending.

You would have to show us your `officer_registration` view and tell us what you expect to see in the ajax handler for further details. **Note that the ajax handler will receive a response generated from your view.** If that is a `jsp`, then the ajax will see some HTML. Is that what you want?

Comment: in my form i used spring form tags to allow binding

Comment: @devdar And which field is `null` in all that? In your image, it seems all fields are set, except the passwords.

Comment: All of the fields were null

Comment: i included a button on the form and made the same call and the form returned data. I included an answer for my solution

Comment: @devdar I think the whole point is that you just weren't doing anything with the response you received in the ajax call. Your controller is not wrong. The solution you provided is just displaying the results in a different way. You could very well have displayed them with javascript like [Emil is suggesting in their answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19622413/438154)

Comment: Ok i see and Emil's answer would mean having to extract the data into each field. I had no idea how to approach this and i thought that once the object was returned the placement of the data in each field would happen just as in my answer. I did not realize the ajax request would have required a little more work to get it working

Comment: @devdar Well yes. The request goes through, but you don't do anything with the response. What do you expect to happen in that case? You gotta do some `success` handling.

Comment: thanks for you assistance thou i honestly had no idea that some success handling was required however now i know. Can you point me to where i can implement multiple validators for a controller. I need to do different types of validation in the same controller. I read where i needed to create a validation facade.

Comment: I have a question open for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682992/springmvc-how-to-use-different-validators-for-an-object-based-on-the-function-th

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the answers to the question however as you all correctly identified the new ModelAndView was indeed returning a new Object. What i observed was the url was not changing when the request was made, it remained as

`http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/officer_registration.htm`

There for it was the incorrect view.

I decided to include a button on my page to allow the user to view the profile details:

```
<button id= "view" class="btn" value ="save"   onclick= "submitPage('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getOfficer/<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("userName")%>.htm');" type="button" ${viewbtn}>View Profile</button>
```

Now all i did was remove the ajax request and included the button, i left the controller code as is. When the request was made the form returned with data and the url read

```
http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getOfficer/jeff.htm
```

This worked perfectly, i am a beginner at Spring MVC so i made not be able to explain why this worked over the ajax request since both hit the controller and both used the same return statements.